# Module not found while bundling Angular 2 project using Webpack

Tags: angular, webstorm, bundling-and-minification, angular2-build

I'm using WebStorm 2016.3 to create an Angular 2 Project. I've followed this post to bundle my project:
https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/webpack.html

When I typed command `npm start` it showed me a list of errors:

[image: Module not found]

I've changed `templateUrl` in every file to `src/components/<template url>` but it still showed those errors.

Can anyone help me please ?

Comment: `@types/node` add in the tsconfig.json then you can `require()` it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this: `../views/main-application.html`

The url is starting relative to the current path of your .ts file.
So you need to navigate up first.

Comment: Your answer worked.
Please help me with:

ERROR in ./src/components/views/shared/navigation-bar.component.ts
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '../views/shared/navigation-bar.component.html' in 'F:\Programming\DotNet\Web\Fullstack\ASP.NET Core\iConfess\A-SOURCE_CODE\B-CLIENT\A-WEB\Adminis
tration\src\components\views\shared'
 @ ./src/components/views/shared/navigation-bar.component.ts 26:22-78
 @ ./src/modules/main-application.module.ts
 @ ./src/main.ts
 @ multi (webpack)-dev-server/client?http://localhost:3000 ./src/main.ts

Comment: I think you should read up on `file paths` ;). In cases where the files are in the exact same folder, use this: `./navigation-bar.component.html`